# Como controlar a espessura/grossura da tag 'strike, del, s', a famosa linha por cima do texto

Tags: html, html5

Hoje estava a desenvolver um projeto e cheguei a um ponto que pela primeira vez na vida decidi fazer uso da tag `<strike>` do HTML. Não sei se era do estilo da fonte que estava a utilizar, mas a linha por cima do texto quase não se notava. O que me levou à questão:

Existe alguma maneira de controlar o tamanho (espessura/grossura) da linha por cima do texto?

```html
A tag "strike" adiciona uma <strike>linha por cima de um texto</strike>.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui está uma solução alternativa para o uso das tags `<strike>`, `<del>` ou `<s>`mais maleável e que nos dá mais controlo não apenas para a espessura da linha mas também para a cor da mesma e adaptá-la para vários tipos de necessidades:

> ### Informação adicional:
>
> De acordo com a [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strike.asp), parece que a tag `<strike>` **não é suportada no HTML5**. Para usar esta tag no HTML5 devemos utilizar `<del>` ou `<s>` em vez disso.

```css
.strikeText {
    position: relative;
}
.strikeText::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.20rem;   /* Muda o tamanho da espessura da linha para o desejado aqui */
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
Lorem <span class="strikeText">IPSUM DOLOR</span> sit amet
<br/>
<h1>Lorem <span class="strikeText">IPSUM DOLOR</span> sit amet</h1>
```